# Count number of points that are inside a pre-defined grid

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes X,Y coordinates and I want to know how points in my dataset fall within each square in a grid that I've pre-defined.

Here is some sample code that generates the following plot.

What I'd like to be able to do is assign a Group ID to each observation that tells you which square that point falls in. That way I can then count the number of points within each Group ID

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))

  ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cut` on the `x` and `y` coordinates with breaks every 25 or whatever, then you can use `dplyr` to count by group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(
  cut_x = cut(X1, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25), include.lowest = T),
  cut_y = cut(X2, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25), include.lowest = T)
) %>%
count(cut_x, cut_y)
# # A tibble: 16 x 3
#    cut_x    cut_y        n
#    <fct>    <fct>    <int>
#  1 [0,25]   [0,25]       6
#  2 [0,25]   (25,50]      4
#  3 [0,25]   (50,75]      6
#  4 [0,25]   (75,100]     9
#  5 (25,50]  [0,25]       3
#  6 (25,50]  (25,50]      2
#  7 (25,50]  (50,75]      6
#  8 (25,50]  (75,100]     6
#  9 (50,75]  [0,25]       5
# 10 (50,75]  (25,50]      6
# 11 (50,75]  (50,75]      6
# 12 (50,75]  (75,100]     4
# 13 (75,100] [0,25]       8
# 14 (75,100] (25,50]     13
# 15 (75,100] (50,75]     10
# 16 (75,100] (75,100]     6
```

Comment: Amazing! Would you be then able to convert that mutated data back into a plot which shows the grid you created and shades each square according to the number of points in that square

Comment: You don't need this data for that. `ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + stat_bin_2d(binwidth = 25) + geom_point(color = "white")`

Comment: I understand that. But I actually want the underlying data that goes with each square/bin, not just the plot.

Comment: Then instead of `count` use `group_by(cut_x, cut_y) %>% mutate(n_bin = n())` and you'll have each point, it's bin, and the count of points in that bin. There's not a great way to get `0` and `25` out of `[0,25]`--you could use regular expressions. You might want to ask a new question there.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was overthinking it the whole time. Thank you for your help